# Ubuntu: how to enter a directory in shell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

On my Desktop I have created a folder called "Files", I would like to know how to access that folder through a shell script

Comment: Uh... English please.

Comment: Ok, done.  Show your effort please?

Comment: @user202729 is already in English

Comment: Useful information for askers: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 2):

When in Linux file system using bash you can navigate to the home directory in many ways:

After you reach the home directory everything is easy from there including reaching Desktop.

> The `~` or `$HOME` reference:
>   In Linux based systems  the keyword `~` or `$HOME` refers to the home directory of the computer.

For example say you are currently at `/bin`, to navigate to home if you know your username you would do :

```
$ cd /home/yourusername
#The directory is now switched to :
$ pwd #This command stands for print working directory
'/home/yourusername'
```

Now you can do it alternatively by:
(Again assuming you are in `/bin`)

```
$ cd $HOME
$ pwd
'/home/yourusername'
#Alternatively
$ cd /bin
$ cd ~
$ pwd
'/home/yourusername'
```

**These shortcuts let you go to home without writing much and are even recommended.**

Now for your problem you can easily navigate to your folder by:

> `cd ~/Desktop/Files/`

Comment: Your outputs may not have prompts `$` before them `;-)` Anyways elaborate enough. ++

Comment: Yeah sorry, i'll fix it!